# Getting a The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference error in java, but I dont have any ampersands in my xml file

Tags: java, xml

I am getting the error

```
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

but I don't have any ampersands in my XML document! Does anyone know why this might happen? Here is the XML document I am trying to parse:

```
<rss version= "2.0" >
<channel>
<item>
<title>Best iPad strategy games</title>
<link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/198mhX3FVmw/story01.htm</link>          </item>
<item>
<title>Share your life with friends in real time with Spin</title>
<link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/9G84sETG_9I/story01.htm</link>    </item>
<item>
<title>How to stop receiving notifications from a website in OS X Mavericks</title>
<link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/IyxFbLcmoOE/story01.htm</link>   </item>
<item>
<title>iPad mini with Retina Display hitting resellers in the UK, 4G LTE models still     look scarce</title>
<link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/FGTUITMMR0E/story01.htm</link>  </item>
<item>
<title>Procraster for iPhone helps you fight procrastination and break down large projects</title>
<link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/o5ATGmzDthw/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>Pad & Quill brings ages-old craftsmanship to all new leather bags and sleeves</title>        <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/NJzAu_PyQNo/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>BillGuard 4.0 for iPhone brings spending analytics, savings alerts, and more</title>   <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/HY4zCH7l1QM/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>GTA: San Andreas coming to iOS in December, game controller support in tow</title><link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/SVNSBiViJdk/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>QuizUp developer Plain Vanilla fixes server issues that left user data vulnerable</title><link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/Nzhq0f5O3Ns/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>Iterate 58: Paul Haddad on Tweetbot 3</title><link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/XJ4dCJWZFVo/story01.htm</link></item>
<\item><title>Deal of the Day: Incipio EDGE PRO Hard Shell Slider Case for iPhone 5S</title><link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/ypt-j2OBqOM/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>Moshi Ionbank 10k battery pack review: Good looks and plenty of power</title>   <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/0HUTAMqX82k/story01.htm</link></item>
<item><title>Infinity Blade goes free for Black Friday week</title>    <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/q0XdepWSTiM/story01.htm</link></item>    <item><title>Procreate 2 for iPad now available, adds 64-bit, iOS 7 design, new GPU    accelerated filters, and more</title>   
</channel></rss>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There are ampersands in your document (at least one); and `<\item>` is certainly wrong. Use a proper editor (e.g. Notepad++ with XML Plugin) to spot this kind of errors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you do have an ampersand:

```
<item><title>Pad & Quill
```

Try

```
<item><title>Pad &amp; Quill
```

Also, this was probably a typo: `<\item><title>Deal of the Day` which you can correct by removing the backslash.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I replaced '&' with &#38;

Answer (score 4):

In string.xml

Every ampersand should be replaced by

```
    &amp;
```