# Invalid XML: Error on line . The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: xml, itunes, podcast

I'm trying to upload this to iTunes but I keep getting the same error back. I don't even have any &'s in it at this point and when I ran it through W3school's validator it said that all was good. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">

<channel>
<title>The Regulars</title>
<link>http://theregularspodcast.tumblr.com/</link>
<language>en-us</language>
<copyright>The Regulars, 2015</copyright>
<itunes:subtitle>EP1 Paying for butts and RIP Konami</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:author>The Regulars</itunes:author>
<itunes:summary>Christopher and Matthew talk about mostly video game news. Sometimes we talk about other stuff too.</itunes:summary>
<description>WHAT IS GOING ON AT KONAMI, WHY DOES A HORSE BUTT COST £60</description>
<itunes:owner>
<itunes:name>The Regulars</itunes:name>
<itunes:email>theregularsforgiven@gmail.com</itunes:email>
</itunes:owner>
<itunes:image href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56667917/logo.png" />
<itunes:category text="Games and Hobbies">
<itunes:category text="Video Games"/>
</itunes:category>

<item>
<title>EP1 Paying for butts and RIP Konami?</title>
<itunes:author>Matthew Starkey</itunes:author>
<itunes:subtitle>Episode 1</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:summary>Chris and Matthew talk about the recent paid mods feature on steam, what is going on with Konami and other related topics</itunes:summary>
<enclosure url="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56667917/The%20Regulars%20-%20EP%201%20-%20Paying%20for%20Anuses%20and%20RIP%20Konami.mp3" length="122341985" type="audio/mpeg" />
<guid>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56667917/The%20Regulars%20-%20EP%201%20-%20Paying%20for%20Anuses%20and%20RIP%20Konami.mp3</guid>
<pubDate>Wed, 29 April 2015</pubDate>
<itunes:duration>1:03:43</itunes:duration>
<itunes:keywords>video games aoncefreeman forgivenpast the regulars skyrim valve steam konami hideo kojima metal gear solid silent hills paid mods</itunes:keywords>
<itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>
</item>


</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: There is no `&` in that document. If you are uploading the document exactly as shown, the application is wrong to output this error.

Comment: Have a look at (among a ton of other question like this one, just search "*[xml] entity name must immediately follow*" on SO) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230551/getting-a-the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-referenc

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official iTunes podcast specs](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html), the category *Games & Hobbies* must contain an HTML entity equivalent of ampersand in the RSS feed. 
In your specific case, the use of the word "and" rather than an ampersand does not correspond to any existing iTunes category (hence, the error in iTunes). Simply replace it with:

```
  Games &amp; Hobbies
```

Additionally, take into account that *Video Games* is a sub category of *Games & Hobbies*, so the correct sintax for your iTunes category tags in the podcast RSS feed is:

```
<itunes:category text="Games &amp; Hobbies">
<itunes:category text="Video Games" />
</itunes:category>
```