# My RSS feed only show few posts

Tags: php, rss, rss2

I'm trying to create an auto feed for my CMS using PDO.
Here's my code. It works but only few posts shown. What's wrong with my code.

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
//header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8"); 
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
echo '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">';
echo '<channel>';
?>
    <title>Authorized Honda Auto Dealer | Serang Cilegon</title>
    <link>https://hondaautoserang.com/</link>
    <atom:link href="https://hondaautoserang.com/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <description>authorized honda auto dealer: dealer resmi mobil honda serang &amp; honda cilegon. beli mobil di serang terbukti lebih murah. Cek info harga &amp; promo terbaru: 087774040777.</description>
    <language>id-id</language>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2017 hondaautoserang.com</copyright>
    <?php
    $sqlFeed = "SELECT * FROM honda_post ORDER BY id DESC";
    $execFeed = $pdo->query($sqlFeed);
    $execFeed->execute();
    $fetchFeed = $execFeed->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($fetchFeed){
        foreach($fetchFeed as $r){
            $id = $r['id'];
            $title = $r['title'];
            $description = $r['description'];
            $publisher = $r['publisher'];
            $article = $r['article'];
            $image = $r['image'];
            $url = $r['url'];
            $date = $r['date'];
            $category = $r['category'];
            //tampilkan
            echo '<item>';
            echo '<title>'.$r['title'].'</title>';
            echo '<description>'.$r['description'].'</description>';
            echo '<category>'.$r['category'].'</category>';
            //echo '<content:encoded><![CDATA['.html_entity_decode($article, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8').']]></content:encoded>';
            echo '<link>'.$r['url'].'</link>';
            echo '<pubDate>'.$r['date'].'</pubDate>';
            //echo '<dc:creator>'.$r['publisher'].'</dc:creator>';
            echo '<guid isPermaLink="true">'.$r['url'].'</guid>';
            echo '</item>';
            }
        }
    ?>
<?php

echo '</channel>';
echo '</rss>';
?>
```

When I change into ORDER BY id ASC, only 10 posts show
(There are 21 posts correctly formatted published right now).

Comment: Proof or didn't happen. [How to create an MCVE for a PDO related problem.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: Proof. Here's the rss page: https://hondaautoserang.com/feed/

Comment: it means that your code displays exact number of records in the table.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  wait, I see in google chrome my feed shows all posts (as I hope) but not in mozilla. is it because of the `header'?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Most likely it's just Mozilla

Comment: So, the problem is that mozilla? If it is right, my question does not need answer since the question does not refer to the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked back into my pdo codes, no problem. But it is because of the ampersand in that title which is **invalid** according to *mozilla browsers* and *google feedburner*.

Solution:
All Ampersands must be change into `&amp;`
Then I use this to change all `&` in the `<title>`,`<description>` by using this follows:

```
$title = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $r['title']);
$description = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $r['description']);
```

and it works as I wish

Here's the references: [Getting a The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference error in java, but I dont have any ampersands in my xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230551/getting-a-the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-referenc)

**Note:**
But, this question **is not duplicate** since the question is different of the reference :p

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the following? :

`$sqlFeed = "SELECT * FROM honda_post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 21";`